# Protractor Mocha-Allure-Reporter : Only the first "expect" failure for a testcase is logged in the report

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai, allure, chai-as-promised

I'm using protractor with mocha-allure reporter.
In a test, when multiple "expect" statements are there,only the first "expect" statement result gets logged in the report.Please find sample code below

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('Allure report for multiple expect', function() {

 it('Check Allure', function(done) {
    expect("first checkpoint").to.equal("is displayed")
    expect("second checkpoint").to.equal("is not displayed")
    expect("third checkpoint").to.equal("is not displayed")
});      

})
```

The allure report displays only first failure
[Allure Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwSej.png)

I need all the failures for all the expect statements in the testcase.
Is there any way i can achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, but only by an own test case for each expectation.

Long answer:
It is always a good pattern to only have one expectation per test - as a failing test should tell you **exactly** what went wrong. To have several expectations in one test case is only useful if they somehow belong together - meaning that if one fails, it doesn't interest you for that moment which other ones fail as they all have a common cause for failure anyways (which you need to adress).

So my suggestion in your case would be to really split them up in three tests.